# IIS 5.1/6.0 Differences with DataGrid and SqlDataSource Refresh

Tags: web-applications, caching, iis-6, sqldatasource, iis-5

I'm having a strange problem here...

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 application that has a GridView and a SqlDataSource on the Default.aspx.  The GridView is databound to the SqlDataSource.  The GridView has a button for each row called "View" that sends the user to a separate page where the row can be edited.

I have two installations of this application - one on my development laptop, which is XP running IIS 5.1 and another on a Windows 2003 server running IIS 6.0.  The web.config files are identical, the IIS configuration properties are identical, and it's hitting the same database.

On my laptop the behavior I see is "correct", and goes like this:
1. Open page, select page 15 of the datagrid via the paging links.
2. Click the view button for a record, view the edit page.
3. Click the "Back" button and you are returned to the Default.aspx page, and the GridView is reloaded/refreshed with new data.  Clicking View again takes you to the proper item.

On the server, I see this:
1. Open page, select page 15 of the datagrid via the paging links.
2. Click the view button for a record, view the edit page.
3. Click the "Back" button and you are returned to the Default.aspx page, and the GridView is **NOT** reloaded with new data (it pops up immediately).  Clicking View again takes you to **WRONG** item.

Obviously there's some sort of caching problem, but I can't figure it out...any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact reason for it, or the cause of it, but as I expected, it was a caching problem.  When I add the statement:

```
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
```

To the Default.aspx.cs, the problem goes away.  It's not surprising that the back button screws up the request pattern, but I did find it surprising that the IIS 5.1 running on my laptop handles the back button better than IIS 6.0...